# rich:autocomplete strange behaviour

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We are upgrading from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2. 
We are using apache myfaces 2.1 and rich faces 4.3.

We are facing very strange issue with `<rich:autocomplete>`. Below is the xhtml code.

```
  <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="2" autocompleteMethod="#{bean.getData}"  
                    var="result" value="#{bean.inputData}">
                                <h:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{result}" />
                            </h:column> 
  </rich:autocomplete>
```

Following is the scenario , when an input is entered in an autocomplete input box , suggetions are shown - that is bean.getData method is called.
Surprisingly , after any of the suggestion is selected , bean.getData method is called again with chosen option value , which I believe is not the correct behaviour 
since user has selected an option and not typed any input.

I don't want the bean.getData method to be called again. Is there any alternative ?

Please help.

**EDIT 1** 
Since I am running a db query to get suggestion values , they are different than the actual input value typed to get suggestions. That is if I type "at" , my sugegstions could be "check me" . I understand that once prefix for search is changed , suggestions are evaluated again , but here i am not changing the prefix but selecting the entire suggestion value.

**EDIT 2**
Providing the context the issue occured with.

When autoCompleted method is called , it populates a hashMap with all the suggestions with CustomUserObject as the value. 
Below is the code for this :

```
 public List<String> getData(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String input) {

    Map<String, CustomUserObject> userMap = new HashMap<String, CustomUserObject>();
    //get users from db 
List<CustomUserObject> users = bean.fetchUserList(input);

//put users in map 
    for (CustomUserObject user : users) {
        userMap.put(user.id, user) ;
    }

    List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //convert the list to List<String> 
    if(userList != null && !userList.isEmpty()){

        //convert the List<CustomUserObject> to List<String>
    }
    return userList;
}
```

Now because of the issue mentioned in the question , getData is called again and corrupts userMap. 
This map is used to retrieve correct CustomUserObject by comparing it with selected Suggestion like below :

```
if(userMap != null && !userMap.isEmpty()){
            for(CustomUserObject user : userMap.values()){


                if(selectedSuggestion != null && selectedSuggestion.equals(user.name)){
                    //match is found 
                //set variables to update ui at re-render 

                }
                //no match found  
            //set variables to update ui at re-render

            }
        }
```

**EDIT 3** 
In addition to above issues , it seems that there is no "nothing label" attribute for `rich:autocomplete` which was present for `rich:suggestionBox` which comes into picture when there is no result found.
This issue alongwith above issue is really making a difficult job to get this component working same as `rich:suggestionBox`

Comment: Hi Atul, what do you do with the selected suggestion - is it written into another value-field or something? Does that part work?

Comment: @L-Ray:added context for the issue occured.

Comment: Just tried it locally, but don't see any way to achieve it that way right now. I trief nesting a `<f:ajax event="itemselect" execute="" />` in the autocomplete to prevent executing the method, not success.

Comment: @L-Ray: Thanks for your update.Last choice is modify application logic to compemsate for above issue.But what i am thinking is using a4j:js function at onSelect event of autocomplete suggestion value and using actionListener in a4:js function.My question here is , is it possible to set a request param inside actionListener using facesContext and use that param in acutoComplete method .If that param is set , don't execute method , return.Here I am assuming that jsFuction and autoComplete method are both called in same request

Comment: IMO, that might fail: autocomplete and your suggestion are both actionListener... So there is no given order who get's executed first. ValueChangeListener are invoked earlier - if the ValueChangeEvent gives you a possibility to figure out if it was invoked as "change" or as "selectItem"-event, you might have a chance there. We actually really changed the application-logic.